# crash in the application in libicuuc.so

Tags: android, crash, android-ndk

I am facing crashes in the libicuuc.so file. Which is not part of myapplication. I have native code in the file libevrc.so (EVRC Codec). While decoding i am facing below crash. Googled and tried a log with the information i got on Google. But still not able to resolve this error.
Below is the dump, pls let me know if any one knows about this. A native function called decode_evrc will be called repeatedly and then the decoded information is written to the speaker with AudioTrack.write() API. After some time it is crashing but not able to figure out where and why it is crashing. And also if anyone have how to decode the native code (as there will be dump of registers, stack and counters) please fwd to my mail id aluvala.suman@gmail.com
Please help me :(.

```
    10-05 17:52:44.356: INFO/DEBUG(6139): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    10-05 17:52:44.383: INFO/DEBUG(6139): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-I9000/GT-I9000/GT-I9000:2.2/FROYO/DDJP6:user/release-keys'
    10-05 17:52:44.387: INFO/DEBUG(6139): pid: 6287, tid: 6289  >>> com.mtrl.android.app.ui <<<
    10-05 17:52:44.391: INFO/DEBUG(6139): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000000
    10-05 17:52:44.399: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  r0 00000000  r1 100ffa80  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
    10-05 17:52:44.410: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  r4 002bc560  r5 aded8ae8  r6 00000000  r7 adec6f58
    10-05 17:52:44.414: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  r8 100ffad0  r9 4300bf98  10 4300bf84  fp 100ffe30
    10-05 17:52:44.422: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  ip 00000000  sp 100ffa70  lr ade597dd  pc 00000000  cpsr 00000010
    10-05 17:52:44.422: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  d0  643a64696f72646e  d1  6472656767756265
    10-05 17:52:44.426: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  d2  0069007400630002  d3  0079007400690001
    10-05 17:52:44.430: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  d4  003000300031002c  d5  00300033002c0036
    10-05 17:52:44.430: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  d6  0033002c00320030  d7  002c003100300030
    10-05 17:52:44.442: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
    10-05 17:52:44.442: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    10-05 17:52:44.446: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    10-05 17:52:44.449: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    10-05 17:52:44.453: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  d16 0000000000000001  d17 3fe999999999999a
    10-05 17:52:44.457: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  d18 42eccefa43de3400  d19 3fe00000000000b4
    10-05 17:52:44.461: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  d20 4008000000000000  d21 3fd99a27ad32ddf5
    10-05 17:52:44.469: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  d22 3fd24998d6307188  d23 3fcc7288e957b53b
    10-05 17:52:44.469: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  d24 3fc74721cad6b0ed  d25 3fc39a09d078c69f
    10-05 17:52:44.469: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
    10-05 17:52:44.473: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
    10-05 17:52:44.473: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
    10-05 17:52:44.477: INFO/DEBUG(6139):  scr 80000012
    10-05 17:52:44.610: INFO/DEBUG(6139):          #00  pc 00000000  
    10-05 17:52:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(6139):          #01  pc 000597da  /system/lib/libicuuc.so
    10-05 17:52:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(6139):          #02  pc 0000d828  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so
    10-05 17:52:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(6139):          #03  pc 00016df4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-05 17:52:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(6139):          #04  pc 00045244  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-05 17:52:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(6139):          #05  pc 0001bd58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-05 17:52:44.618: INFO/DEBUG(6139):          #06  pc 00022754  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-05 17:52:44.618: INFO/DEBUG(6139):          #07  pc 000215f4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-05 17:52:44.618: INFO/DEBUG(6139):          #08  pc 0005c584  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-05 17:52:44.621: INFO/DEBUG(6139):          #09  pc 0005c7b4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-05 17:52:44.621: INFO/DEBUG(6139):          #10  pc 00051ff6  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-05 17:52:44.621: INFO/DEBUG(6139):          #11  pc 00052082  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-05 17:52:44.621: INFO/DEBUG(6139):          #12  pc 00052558  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-05 17:52:44.625: INFO/DEBUG(6139):          #13  pc 0004f9a8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    10-05 17:52:44.625: INFO/DEBUG(6139):          #14  pc 000111b0  /system/lib/libc.so
    10-05 17:52:44.625: INFO/DEBUG(6139):          #15  pc 00010ca0  /system/lib/libc.so
    10-05 17:52:44.625: INFO/DEBUG(6139): code around pc:
    10-05 17:52:44.625: INFO/DEBUG(6139): code around lr:
    10-05 17:52:44.625: INFO/DEBUG(6139): ade597bc 000fe8ae e8972304 94050007 0007e88e 
    10-05 17:52:44.629: INFO/DEBUG(6139): ade597cc 9300aa0b 9201a904 69204633 47e04632 
    10-05 17:52:44.629: INFO/DEBUG(6139): ade597dc c084f8df 100cf855 c000f8d4 d017458c 
    10-05 17:52:44.629: INFO/DEBUG(6139): ade597ec f10d4a1c 18ad0e10 cd0f355c 000fe8ae 
    10-05 17:52:44.629: INFO/DEBUG(6139): ade597fc e895ab0b 94050007 0007e88e 21042200 
    10-05 17:52:44.629: INFO/DEBUG(6139): stack:
    10-05 17:52:44.629: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa30  002a4668  [heap]
    10-05 17:52:44.629: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa34  002a4688  [heap]
    10-05 17:52:44.633: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa38  100ffad0  
    10-05 17:52:44.633: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa3c  4300bfa0  
    10-05 17:52:44.633: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa40  4300bf8c  
    10-05 17:52:44.633: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa44  afd0bfc9  /system/lib/libc.so
    10-05 17:52:44.633: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa48  00000000  
    10-05 17:52:44.633: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa4c  afd10560  /system/lib/libc.so
    10-05 17:52:44.633: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa50  afd4372c  /system/lib/libc.so
    10-05 17:52:44.637: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa54  afd437d0  /system/lib/libc.so
    10-05 17:52:44.637: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa58  002a4810  [heap]
    10-05 17:52:44.637: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa5c  002a4890  [heap]
    10-05 17:52:44.637: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa60  100ffad0  
    10-05 17:52:44.637: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa64  4300bfa0  
    10-05 17:52:44.637: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa68  df002777  
    10-05 17:52:44.637: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa6c  e3a070ad  
    10-05 17:52:44.637: INFO/DEBUG(6139): #01 100ffa70  00000004  
    10-05 17:52:44.637: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa74  100ffa9c  
    10-05 17:52:44.641: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa78  002a42a0  [heap]
    10-05 17:52:44.641: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa7c  002a42d0  [heap]
    10-05 17:52:44.641: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa80  0001001c  [heap]
    10-05 17:52:44.641: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa84  002bc560  [heap]
    10-05 17:52:44.641: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa88  00000000  
    10-05 17:52:44.641: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa8c  00000000  
    10-05 17:52:44.641: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa90  00000000  
    10-05 17:52:44.641: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa94  00000000  
    10-05 17:52:44.641: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa98  00000000  
    10-05 17:52:44.641: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffa9c  00000000  
    10-05 17:52:44.645: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffaa0  afd42328  /system/lib/libc.so
    10-05 17:52:44.645: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffaa4  002bc560  [heap]
    10-05 17:52:44.645: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffaa8  00000000  
    10-05 17:52:44.645: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffaac  4001c818  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/zygote/0 (deleted)
    10-05 17:52:44.645: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffab0  4300bfa0  
    10-05 17:52:44.645: INFO/DEBUG(6139):     100ffab4  ad10d82b  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so
```

Thanks & Regards,
SSuman185

Comment: It seems libicuuc.so call an invaild address? Could you update rom for your device?

Comment: I'm also having this issue. @Suman How you found a solution?